# how much is Vietnam train ticket?

Tags: tickets, vietnam

if possible to purchase direct from train station without through an agent, how much cost a SEAT ONLY ticket from Lao Cai to Hanoi on 1 of the morning departing trains from Lao Cai train station ?
also how much to carry a motorbike on the same train ?

Comment: I'm afraid that the two "how much" questions you ask are shopping questions: the price is bound to vary over time and thus any answer will be outdated by then. I would edit those out and stick with the booking-a-seat question.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the time you have for your travel, it's a better option to take the night train (the train is VERY slow, so you lose quite some time during the day).

Regarding buying the ticket, ours was bought by the hotel manager, and comparing to prices seen online there was no difference, so I assume there was no additional fee, compared to a travel agency, and he was really kind, at the point he accompanied us to our seats!

For the rates, indeed they would change a lot, but you can have a good idea on seat61 : http://www.seat61.com/Vietnam.htm#Hanoi-to-Lao-Cai

Depending on the season you travel to Vietnam, it could be risky to buy the ticket at the station on the departure day, because there might be lots of tourists, so the trains could be full.